# How do I ensure questions are displayed at the same time for all players in socket.io quiz game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a multiplayer quiz game that runs in the client's browser. It uses socket.io and node.js on server side and javascript on client side.

Questions are picked from a database and sent to each player at the same time but slower internet connections could mean that they will receive them at different times.

**Possible solution:**

- Send a timestamp with each question which tells the browser when to display the question. The timestamp would be (send time + x seconds) to account for connection lag. However, if the client knew how to use the console they could intercept the question as soon as it arrives and therefore see it before all the other players.

So how could I ensure that no player has an unfair advantage ad receives questions before the others?

Answer (score 1):

You cant. What matters is that all players believe they are playing at the same time, that players get the same time to answer and that the result is determined at the sever. Nobody gets an advantage as they have the same amount of time to answer and the time to answer is the time between question presentation and answer given. At most they will only be a few seconds apart and clients will be total unaware they are not playing simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be store info on a server when the user received questions and user submitted the answer. 
As the addition, you define timeframe in which all user can submit their answers (aka **round**). 
You can define winner by smallest diff in timestamps. Socket.io delay should not produce any significant problems in the logic as seems you send not so many data and the same time sockets have logic with heartbeats and in case you client will have connection problem  - he will be disconnected. To reduce the risk of this logic to be broken you can reduce the time which Socket.io library can consider as the broken connection - `pingInterval` and `pingTimeout` can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write server side logic to send questions only when all your participant's login and their socket connection is established..;-)